# onreadystatechange not triggered when scroll in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I know that UIWebView will pause the js and UI thread when is scrolling. but I found that in my app, it lost the response of HTTP request, and the xhr.onreadystatechange event is not triggered after response returned.

After I use `overflow: scroll`, the bug does not appear again. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: it can only be reproduced in our app, this app is so complex.....i use zepto to send ajax, with the bad request, xhr.onreadystatechange is only triggered   once with readystate = 1, and not triggered any more. but in charles or the dev-tool of safari, the response is returned with 200 status.